# Joint PDF when 0<x<2y

Tags: probability-theory

Is there an better way to compute this? I think I am missing a trick here:

Let $(X,Y)$ have the joint pdf:

$$
   f\left(x,y\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       4e^{-(x+2y)}, & \mbox{if} &0<x<2y<\infty,\\ 
       0, && \mbox{otherwise}.
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$$

Find the marginal pdf, mean and variance of $X$. What family of distributions does it belong to?

I "ignored" the $2y$ in $0<x<2y<\infty$ and calculated as I would for a number range, inserting the "$2y$" in the integral.

Marginal pdf of $X$ is $-2e^{-3x}$

Mean of $X$ is $\frac{4}{3}ye^{-6y}$

Variance of $X$ is $\frac{4}{3}y^2e^{-6y}- \frac{4}{9}ye^{-6y} + \frac{4}{27}e^{-6y}-\frac{16}{9}y^2e^{-12y}-\frac{6}{27}ye^{-12y}-\frac{4}{81}e^{-12y} $

This seems a little excessive, so perhaps there is a simpler way?

Comment: Your equation for the marginal pdf of $X$ should be positive and $=2e^{-2x}$ because $\frac x2<y<\infty$. Other than that, a simple way to check your answer is to plug in some values for y?

Comment: Also have a think about the difference between how $X$ is bounded when joint with $Y$ and when it is marginal. I think you'll find a very simple answer for both the mean and variance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand the marginal pdf was incorrect. I still end up doing integration by parts to get the expected value and variance though. I'll keep working at it. Thanks again!